# Python script can't find virtualenv path

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

Basically, a python script I'm running doesn't find the path to a script located in a virtualenv folder, while I can see that script from bash.

Details:
I have Python 2.7 installed globally and OpenCV3.1 installed in virtualenv, with virtualenv located at the path

> `~/.virtualenvs/cvcorrect`

I'm trying to run a script (written by someone else) that requires loading of activate_this.py to run the script. In my case, it is located at

> `~/.virtualenvs/cvcorrect/bin/activate_this.py`

I can see that it is there it when I look into that folder from shell. However, when I run the script, with the correct path, it gives the common

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '~/.virtualenvs/cvcorrect/bin/activate_this.py'

Tried running this both as regular and superuser. Same results. Running in Ubuntu 64 bit in VMWare 15.

Comment: You need to expand tilde: `os.path.expanduser('~/.virtualenvs/cvcorrect/bin/activate_this.py')`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html: "*Unlike a unix shell, Python does not do any automatic path expansions. Functions such as expanduser() and expandvars() can be invoked explicitly when an application desires shell-like path expansion.*"

Comment: You could also manually specify the full path to the file...

Comment: os.path.expanduser didn't work for me (os not specified error).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to find and input the full path: `/root/.virtualenvs/cvcorrect/bin/activate_this.py`

This was not as straightforward as usual, because .virtualenvs folder was located in the root folder which was not accessible using GUI. Also, bash shell gave me the path
`~/.virtualenvs/cvcorrect/bin/activate_this.py`

The solution was to cd to the folder from shell and use:

```
readlink -f activate_this.py
```

Which finally gave me the correct path.